# Appear logout button after login PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication, logout

Problem:
I want "logout" make instant appear if I'm logged. Now it only appears when I do Refresh (F5). Is there any way to make it instant appear after login?

```
<?php if ($gebruiker->checkLogout()) { ?>
  <li><a href="logout.php">Loguit</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

**function checkLogout()**

```
function checkLogout(){
       if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
         return true;
       }else {
         return false;
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your code structure like:

```
---------------
Logic for login
---------------

------------
Menu Section
------------
```

With this structure, when user login is successful the `SESSION` are set at the top, so that you can check them in menu section and on that behalf you can show the logout button. In the current scenario the logic section is placed after menu section that's why you have to make another request to check it.

Comment: I did what u said, and this helped for me. I had to think the logic way with SESSION's. Thanks

Comment: Sounds great !!

Comment: Is this a college project ?

Comment: That's great!. You guys are doing great work at college level

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply use this

in the navigation itself

```
<?php if($_SESSION['login'])

echo <a href="logout.php">Loguit</a></li>';
else{
echo '<li><a href="login.php">Login/Registreren</a></li>';
}
?>
```

make sure you redirect it and put session_start at the beginning

Comment: oww i forgot? does your session contains boolean or string, if its boolean that can work. plus in your login function you should use header('Location:http/your_link') function